# Failed: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

Tags: javascript, protractor

Need to find the count of the element from arryelement and if the count>1 then need to click

```
/*search name is clinic name
clinicsearch is the arrayelement which has the list of clinic name list from the table*/
public SearchAndSelectClinicA(SearchName:string){
  this.ClinicSearch.sendKeys(SearchName);
  this.SearchIcon.click(); //click on the icon to get the clinic names
  this.SearchedClinic.count().then(function(count){
    //get the count of elements which are there in the Searchedclinic element array
    if(count>1){
      this.SearchedClinic.each(function(rows){ 
        /*Failed: Cannot read property 'SearchedClinic' of undefined 
          (Error gets displayed when it comes to above line.*/
        rows.getText().then(function(value){
          if(value.indexOf(SearchName)){
            //Click the element if the statement is satisfied
            rows.click();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Please help me in solving this

> Failed: Cannot read property 'SearchedClinic' of undefined.

Is getting displayed.

It is able to execute till the if statement. Later it throws error as specifief above and the exection stops immediately

Comment: can you edit your post i think you mismatch to insert code sample, it is difficult to read

Comment: Show the error message you get. What has your debugging shown you? What research have you done? These details should be in the question as an [edit]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript each function has an implicit `this`.  You need be careful when use `this` in nested function situation.

Following picture illustrate those `this` come from which function.

[image]

The second `this.SearchedClinic` will try to access `this` belongs to the nested function: `function(count){}`, which has no a property called `SearchedClinic`.

You expect that `this` point to the upper one. So you need to assign the top `this` to another variable as below:

[image]

Now `me` is point to the top `this`, you can use it in any nested function as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your `function(rows)` creates a new closure. That means that `this` within that scope is not necessarily the same as the `this` outside.

A couple solutions are to

1. Define a different variable above such as `var self = this;` the inside the function use

   ```
   self.SearchedClinic`
   ```
2. Use a ES6 function definition that uses the same scope.

   ```
   this.SearchedClinic.count().then((count) => { 
   });
   ```
3. Use `.bind(this)`

   ```
   this.SearchedClinic.count().then((function (count) => { 
   }).bind(this));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

suppose the following code:

```
const result = obj1.printName.call(obj2);
```

using `this` under the function `call` will reference to `obj2` since the first parameter of call() is to explicitly set what `this` refers to.

This is exaclty the problem you're encountering with.

```
this.SearchedClinic.count().then(function(count){ 
    //calling this will reference the parameter count 
}
```

any `this` in between accolades will reference the first parameter of the function.
What you would do, is to declare a global variable: `var searchedClinic = this.SearchedClinic`. Here is your code updated:

```
public SearchAndSelectClinicA(SearchName:string){
  var searchedClinic = this.SearchedClinic;
  this.ClinicSearch.sendKeys(SearchName);
  this.SearchIcon.click(); //click on the icon to get the clinic names
  this.SearchedClinic.count().then(function(count){
    //get the count of elements which are there in the Searchedclinic element array
    if(count>1){
      searchedClinic.each(function(rows){ 
        rows.getText().then(function(value){
          if(value.indexOf(SearchName)){
            //Click the element if the statement is satisfied
            rows.click();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```